# Cassandra Node details

Tags: cassandra, nosql, nodes

I am new to Cassandra. I install Apache Cassandra on ubuntu 16.04. What I do to know how many nodes my cluster have. if only one node by default?. what happens during the replication process? please help, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new installation gives you one node of Cassandra, so at present you would have a single-node cluster.

Once Cassandra is started and up and running, you can display your cluster topology with the `nodetool status` command, it prints the cluster information.

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/nodetool/status.html

With Cassandra, the data is replicated between nodes according to the replication strategies that you define; in the case of a single-node cluster, replication is not really applicable.

Comment: Again thank you.
I see tokens with a value 256 when I run this command nodetool status in the terminal. 
I think tokens means partition key hash values. if this correct. If I add another node to the cluster. after that, is each node has 128 tokens?

Comment: The tokens refer to the `num_tokens` value that was configured for this node, by default it is 256. Here is more information about this configuration: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html

Comment: @RamS `num_tokens` refers to the number of token ranges that each node is responsible for.  With Cassandra 3, 256 is actually not a good default (way too high), but for standalone it  should work.  The actual number of partition key hash values (within the token ranges) that can be addressed is -2^63 to 2^63.  This answer provides some good detail on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37940630/cassandra-vnodes-and-token-ranges/37982696